# Rails + paperclip + S3 + OSX = OpenSSL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, openssl, paperclip

I'm trying to post to S3 using AWS in development, but it can't find my ssl bundle.  I have it installed for Oauth, and once I tell it where it is, it works fine.  I can't seem to configure AWS to see it properly though.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:
  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Here's my config from my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  :styles => { ... }, 
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id     => ACCESS_KEY,
    :secret_access_key => SECRET_KEY,
    :bucket => BUCKET,
    :ssl_ca_file => '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt'
  }
```

I have attempted to add, `:ssl_verify_peer => false`, and `:use_ssl => false`.  Neither of which work, which makes me think that I'm configuring the AWS gem in the wrong place.  Any suggestions where/how I should be doing this?

I'm using paperclip 2.4.0, and aws-sdk 1.3.8

I should also mention that the error occurs in testing with rspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with help from the github aws-sdk page: https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby

In short, I had to create a specific `config/initializers/aws.rb` that looks like...

```
# load the libraries
require 'aws'
# log requests using the default rails logger
AWS.config(:logger => Rails.logger)
# load credentials from a file
config_path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/../aws.yml")
AWS.config(YAML.load(File.read(config_path)))
```

All i had to do then was move my `config/s3.yml` file to `config/aws.yml`.  And then change my model to use that yml file...

```
has_attached_file :image, 
:styles => { ... }, 
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/aws.yml"
```

And that took care of it.  As I suspected, setting the ssl properties via paperclip using the s3_credentials didn't work because the aws object had already been loaded.

Just for completeness, here's the yml file...

```
development:
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
  bucket: bucket_name
  ssl_ca_file: /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
test:
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
  bucket: bucket_name
  ssl_ca_file: /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
production:
  access_key_id: ...
  secret_access_key: ...
  bucket: bucket_name
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your bucket name?

If you use something like foo.domain.com as the bucket, paperclip will use that as a prefix for the host name (foo.domain.com.aws.amazon.com), which will cause problems with SSL verification.

Try using a bucket name that doesn't resemble a host name, like `mydomain-photos`

The code for determining the url is in fog.rb:

```
      if fog_credentials[:provider] == 'AWS'
        if @options[:fog_directory].to_s =~ Fog::AWS_BUCKET_SUBDOMAIN_RESTRICTON_REGEX
          "https://#{@options[:fog_directory]}.s3.amazonaws.com/#{path(style)}"
        else
          # directory is not a valid subdomain, so use path style for access
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{@options[:fog_directory]}/#{path(style)}"
        end
      else
        directory.files.new(:key => path(style)).public_url
      end
```

and that regex is:

```
     AWS_BUCKET_SUBDOMAIN_RESTRICTON_REGEX = /^(?:[a-z]|\d(?!\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$))(?:[a-z0-9]|\.(?![\.\-])|\-(?![\.])){1,61}[a-z0-9]$/
```

Comment: Ah, interesting, but no dots in the bucket name `domain_env`

Comment: mydomain-photos passes the regex.   underscores or mixed case would fail and be better choices.